# Yum install php v5.4 packages while I have installed php 7

Tags: centos, php, php5, php7

I have installed PHP version 7 on my centOs.

Now I got an error says:

> undefined function mb_internal_encoding()

So I decided to install php-mbstring (using `yum install php-mbstring`) but I face the following error:

> Error: php70u-common conflicts with php-common-5.4.16-43.el7_4.x86_64
>
> Error: php70u-json conflicts with php-common-5.4.16-43.el7_4.x86_64

But now when I install php-mbstring, it wants to install php-mbstring version 5.4.

How can I tell yum to download latest versions of php extensions and packages?

Answer (score 0):

You've both `php5` and `php7` installed in your system which is creating conflict. If you're using `php7` only then remove another version using

```
yum remove php-*
```

Install the necessary `php7` packages only after complet removal of older version. If you need multiple versions of `php` to be installed, please google for particular procedure. It's not very simple.

**Note** While removing softwares with wildcards remember to check what `yum` is going to remove before proceeding further.

Comment: It didn't work, I have delete whole php twice.

Answer (score 0):

Run this:

```
yum remove php php-cli php-common php-gd php-ldap php-mysql php-odbc php-pdo php-pear php-pecl-apc php-pecl-memcache php-pgsql php-soap php-xml php-xmlrpc -y
```

Now run `yum install php-mbstring`

This should help you.

Answer (score 0):

If you need both the official centos php (5.4) and a newer one being simultaneously  installed in your system, IUS repository offers packages with newer releases than centos/epel repos and is using different naming (e.g. php56u, php70u...) to prevent conflicts.

Using ius repository is described here : https://ius.io/GettingStarted/